# Return MySQL timestamp on insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

When I perform an insert statement to a MySQL database in PHP, is there a way to return the auto-generated timestamp or do I need a separate call to the database to retrieve the data?

Edit: I forgot that MySQL doesn't use epoch dates.  I decided to just use an autoincrementing integer and a stored procedure.

Comment: what do you mean by *autoincremented timestamp*? this can possible be done using stored procedure.

Comment: no. at most you can get back the ID of the new record with last_insert_id(), which you can then use in a select to get that timestamp.

Comment: the timestamp is the PK and it's default is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  In the interest of minimizing DB queries, I was hoping that I could return its value without querying the database again.

Comment: wouldn't be an approximate timestamp enough? So you could fetch the current time via PHP and then do the insert query.

Comment: Who the hell downvotes legitimate question?  In response to Benjamin, the possibility of queries at the same time make generating timestamps in code a bad idea since they are the PK.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a separate request to get that information. You can only get the last insert ID of auto incremented tables when doing an INSERT.

Comment: This is pretty much what I expected.  At least the queries are small.

Answer (score 1):

Use a multi-statement query.

1. Select the current timestamp into a variable.
2. insert the row with the timestamp.
3. return (select) the variable to php.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is possible for *last inserted ID* if the `ID` was set as `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed. But for timestamp, I'll advise you to create a `stored procedure` so you will only have single request on the database. Remember that connection into database is costly.

Comment: Hence the question.  I don't want to have to open another query.  The number of total queries is sure to be tiny, and it probably wouldn't matter, but it's no excuse to be sloppy.

Comment: you don't have to open another query. You only need to call the procedure once.

Comment: I was just agreeing with you.

Comment: And I was adding additional info :D

Answer (score 0):

You can return a `last inserted id` after `insert`, like:

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO <TABLE> VALUES (?,?)");
return mysql_insert_id();
?>
```

Comment: this will work in common sense. But if there are fluctuations and the exact time is required that "now" might be later or even earlier than the one in the database row that was just inserted. This might be due to heavy workload and/or traffic on either the fileserver and/or databaseserver. But nonetheless; for common human interaction this would not pose any threat :)

Comment: As I thought it in a general way, so I changed my answer and `return last insert id` for `uniqueness`.